# How can I modify the arguments passed to a core hook?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Due to a recent update of Drupal core, I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_term in
>   taxonomy_field_formatter_view() (line 1601 of taxonomy.module)

Now, this is caused because the [core taxonomy hook `taxonomy_field_formatter_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_field_formatter_view/7) has an argument called `$items` that expects an array of values that have two elements: `tid`, a numeric value, and `taxonomy_term` which is the taxonomy term object.

In the case of my code, each array in `$items` is missing the `taxonomy_term` element.

Now a simple fix would be to hack core and simply set `$item['taxonomy_term'] = taxonomy_term_load($item['tid'])` if it doesn't already exist. But of course, hacking core is a no-no so I'm trying to **find a way to catch the $items argument for `taxonomy_field_formatter_view()` before it is passed to this hook**.

What's the approach here? Would defining `hook_field_formatter_view()` in a custom module and fixing the `$items` argument work? Presumably not because the core hook is going to fall over first, so I'll need to modify it before it's passed into these hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) and replace `taxonomy_field_formatter_view()` to your function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to use one of the [Field formatter API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7) hooks before modifying a Drupal core hook, even with `hook_module_implements_alter`, you might get unpleasant surprises if someone else is using it.

What I'd do is to prepare your items using [hook_field_formatter_prepare_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_prepare_view/7) and as it's passed by reference, it should arrive fine to your formatter_view.